# How to create this kind of SQL trigger?

Tags: sql, triggers, sqlite

Let's say in sqlite3 I create a table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (int a);
```

I want to create a trigger that activates before an insertion into table1. If the number inserted into table1 is greater than 10, then I want the trigger to not allow the insertion. What's the code to do that?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[table1_trigger] 
   ON  [dbo].[table1]
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @a INT 

    SET @a = (SELECT a FROM Inserted)

    IF @a < 10 BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.table1 (a) VALUES (@a)
    END
END
```